# Is there a way to iterate over Bio.trie in a memory-friendly way?

Tags: trie, biopython

I would like to use a Bio.trie as an index for sequences to count how many time each of them occurs in a dataset. The index is created like this:

```
seqs = trie()
for seq in dataset:
    if seqs.has_key(seq):
        seqs[seq] += 1
    else:
        seqs[seq] = 1
```

And after that I would like to extract some information from the trie, e.g. a list of sequences that have been counted only once. It's possible to do it like this:

```
singletons = []
for seq in seqs.keys():
    if seqs[seq] == 1:
        singletons.append(seq)
```

The problem is that the machine I'm working on is low on memory and calling trie.keys() returns a list object which is roughly as large as the trie itself. Is it possible to iterate over the keys using a generator instead of a list, so that you would only get one key at a time?

Comment: What do you want to use as a key? Only the ID of the sequence or the whole sequence? You cannot use a Seq object as key.

Comment: The key is the sequence as a text string. Their IDs are either irrelevant or can be stored in the leaves of the trie.